# implement user activity log in cakePHP

Tags: cakephp, logging

Which is the best method to implement user activity log in cakePHP?
I already gone through these tutorials

1. [logable behavior](http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/alkemann/2008/10/21/logablebehavior)
2. http://www.cakephp.co.uk/user_activity_cakephp_tutorial.html

My aim is to log these activities

1. Login
2. Logout
3. Update Profile
4. Change Password
5. placing an order
6. review order
7. cancel order

where should i write the code for log, in App_controller or App_model or afterSave of each model.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I Guess, that using logable behaviour is a good idea (although get the newest version (see comments in the bakery)). That would be a very "convention-like" way to go.

The second link also provides a nice way to do this, a small amount of neat code (needs some refreshments though).

I think the best place to call this recordActivity function are models callback methods, here's a [list of them](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1048/Callback-Methods).

Answer (score 2):

I  didn't use the behavior, I built my own. I put it on the afterSave (in app_model). You'll want to add a trigger to catch the login actions, though, as they don't do a save.

Comment: can u please provide me with some piece of code for **trigger**. or a link to some tutorial.

Comment: Put a call to your logging method in login/logout see -http://book.cakephp.org/view/1261/login